# How to ignore row Parsing errors in an SQL (Athena) Query

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, trino

We are trying to post `Athena` queries to an external `S3` file, everything works fine but now the data has a corrupt row which has a malformed date. This blows up our system where we are trying to post a simple query like this -

```
Select code 
from  tsummary 
where parse_datetime(checkdate, 'yyyyMMdd') <= current_date
```

is there a way to skip/ignore the failing row within `SQL` itself. with my primitive SQL knowledge it feels there has to be a way to get around this but I can't figure that out.

Comment: correct the malformed data, when you know how the incorrect data look like write an update for it

Comment: when I said Primitive I didn't mean that primitive! -- by external I meant the file is not owned by us and have no control over it.

Comment: Man, can you imagine how much easier our lives would be if our SQL queries could just skip bad data?!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that date is not in the correct format - Presto/Trino provide a potentially useful operator for such cases - [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try):

> Evaluate an expression and handle certain types of errors by returning `NULL`.

```sql
Select code 
from  tsummary 
where try(parse_datetime(checkdate, 'yyyyMMdd')) <= current_date
```

Comment: Does this work on Athena?

Comment: @dfundako yes, cause Athena is based on Presto/Trino (and `try` was added to Presto long ago).

Comment: Can you link to the Athena docs?

Comment: @dfundako which one exactly? In terms of supporting Presto/Trino operators Athena docs tend to link to Presto/Trino docs.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm it is supported. Certain AWS platforms that are based on other things don't support 100% of functionality, like Redshift/Postgres.

Comment: @dfundako yep, there is some mismatch between the supported stuff, but last time I used Athena `try` was working fine.